# How to share on linkedin using "Opengraph" in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, share, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

With reference to the below-mentioned link, we have done a Facebook share. Now our client wants the same kind of experience for LinkedIn as well.

Can anybody suggest a way or approach to achieve the same experience for LinkedIn

Facebook Ref Link:
[Using "share_open_graph" Facebook UI to create dynamic share dialog for quiz results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23514157/using-share-open-graph-facebook-ui-to-create-dynamic-share-dialog-for-quiz-res#)

Comment: Please write a proper question that what you actually want, and what have you done so far. Solutions for something that you're not doing isn't really helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Setup Your Share URL**

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Source: [**Official MSD LinkedIn Share Documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)

**Step 2 - Handle title, description, image, etc.**

Put these into the `<head>` block of your HTML, which, since you are already doing this for Facebook, this part should be done now...

- `<meta property='og:title' content='Title of the article'/>`
- `<meta property='og:image' content='//media.example.com/ 1234567.jpg'/>`
- `<meta property='og:description' content='Description that will show in the preview'/>`
- `<meta property='og:url' content='//www.example.com/URL of the article' />`

Source: [**LinkedIn Share Documentation: Making Your Website Shareable on LinkedIn**](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)

**Step 3 - Verify Everything Went Okay**

Check your URL at the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**.  Insert your URL here (i.e. `example.com`), not the URL you are going to share with (i.e. `linkedin.com?url=example.com`).