# Not able to post on facebook timeline: getting error message "ERROR(#100)The parameter object is required"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb.ui

I have a website. I need to share content on facebook. I had created custom story "Participate in a Engagement" with respective action "Participate" and object "Engagement".My problem is to get explicitly_shared permission from facebook,I need to show user what is going to posted.
When i am posting using FB.api like below, it is posting successfuly.
**Approach 1 :**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : "Some App ID",
          status     : true,    
          cookie     : true,    
          xfbml      : true,     
          version    : 'v2.0',  
        });
      };
    
          // Load the SDK Asynchronously
          (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    
        function postFBShare() {
            var fbparam= {
                            "app_id":"Some App ID",
                            "url":"Some url",
                            "title":'Some Title',
                            "image":[
                                     {url:"Some image url"}
                                     ],
                            "description":'',
                            "explicitly_shared": "true"
                        };
            FB.api(
                      'https://graph.facebook.com/me/{namespace}:participate ',
                      'post',
                      {
                        engagement: fbparam
                      },
                      function(response) {
                        // handle the response
                      }
                    );
        }
    </script>
    <input type="button" value="fb share" onclick="postFBShare();">
```

**Approach 2:**
but to show user wht is going to post i need an object to post.I wrote the following code to achieve this.

```
function preFBAction(videoURL){
                var fbparam= {
                        "app_id":"Some App ID",
                        "type" : {namespace}:engagement,
                        "url":"Some url",
                        "title":'Some Title',
                        "image":[
                                 {url:"Some image url"}
                                 ],
                        "description":'',
                        "explicitly_shared": "true"
                    };
                FB.api(
                          '/app/objects/{namespace}:engagement',
                          'post',
                          {
                            engagement: fbparam
                          },
                          function(response) {
                            // handle the response
                             if (response && !response.error) {
                                 FB.ui(
                                        {
                                            method: 'share_open_graph',
                                            action_type: '{namespace}:participate ',
                                            action_properties: JSON.stringify({engagement:response.id})
                                        },
                                      function(response) {
                                        // handle the response
                                      }
                                    );
                             }
                          }
                        ); 
};
```

**Approach 3:**
I tried with using only FB.ui,but getting following error in share dialog
"Action Requires At Least One Reference: The action you're trying to publish is invalid because it does not specify any reference objects. At least one of the following properties must be specified: other."
The code I tried is-

```
var obj={
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: '{namespace}:participate ',
    action_properties: {engagement:fbparam}     
};
 FB.ui(obj,function(response) {
    // handle the response
});
```

So if someone know how to do this and where I am going wrong, help out.
Thanks!!

**UPDATE**

Using og tags on public page I am able to post on wall successfully and as well as in **Approach 2** if I use "/me/objects/.." in place of "/app/objects.." Post gto posted on facebok but this time i got created in newz feed as well as activity log, which is not according to facebook policies.(similiar problem mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407527/dynamically-generate-description-for-explicitly-shared-open-graph-story-through).)

Comment: haven't got any answer for above question. still if anyone else is spending time on the same.. my suggestion is to go with OG Tags approach. if someone finds any solution with fb.api, kindly add your answer